# How to make a connection of some specific node of scatter plot of matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I had some list:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [1.4,2.5,3.2,4.5]
```

And I named each node:

```
a = (1,1.4)
b = (2,2.5)
c = (3,3.2)
d = (4,4.5)
```

I want `x,y` to be a scatter plot and to have some connection

```
a to c
b to c and d
```

And my code is like:

```
for t in np.arange(5):
     plt.axvline(t)
plt.scatter([1,2,3,4],[1.4,2.5,3.2,4.5])
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1.4,2.5,3.2])
plt.show()
```

But it connect all the node together
How to make a connection to only a to c and b to c and d and also mark `abcd` on my scatter plot?

Comment: A line from point (x1,y1) to point (x2,y2) is plotted via `plt.plot([x1,x2], [y1,y2])`.

Comment: To annotate the points, you can use `plt.text(x,y, 'text')` where x, y are your individual points' coordinates